# position: fixed inside a div not taking proper width in CSS layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position

I'm trying to creating a two-column layout for my website that consists of having fixed `div`s within one of the columns. Below is an overview, an image and my code. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

**Overview:**

- I have two elements that are both 100% in height. The `.user-nav` nav element and the `.container` div element.
- The `.user-nav` element has fixed positioning, a `width` of 75px and a `height` of 100%. The `.container` `div` has 100% of `width`, 100% of `height` and -75px `margin-left` (to account for the `.user-nav width`).
- Inside of the `.container` `div`, there are two more `div` elements: the `.viewport` `div` and the `.right_panel` `div`. (FYI: I wrapped the `.container` element around these 2 `div`s because all the content inside the `.container` `div` is loaded dynamically with jQuery/Ajax.)
- The `.right_panel` `div` is fixed positioned and has a width of 30% and a height of 100%.
- The `.viewport` `div` has a width of 70%. The `.viewport` `div` contains another 3 `div`s, the `.header` `div`, the `.content` `div` and the `.footer` `div`. All three of those `div`s should be 100% of the `.viewport` `div`.
- Both the `.header` and `.footer` `div`s inside the `.viewport` `div` are fixed and have a `height` of 50px. The `.header` `div` has a `top: 0px` applied (to stick to the top) and the `.footer` `div` has a `bottom: 0px` property (to stick to the bottom).
- The `.content` `div` and its contents should be the only thing that scrolls on the page.

**Issue:**

The `.viewport` `div` seems to run longer than 70% and goes under the `.right_panel` `div`. I know that once you give a `div` `position: fixed`, its parent becomes the body. I believe that is where the issue lies.

How can I put a `fixed` `position` `div` inside of another `div`? Are there any other alternatives in creating a layout like this? What other approach should I take? Any suggestions would be helpful.

JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/mikerodriguez/709rcw8a/1/

**Image of layout:**

[image: Asker result]

**CSS**

```css
html{height: 100%;}
body{
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%
}
.user-nav{
    width: 75px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 75px;
}
.viewport{
    width: 70%;
    background: #eee;
}
.header{
    height: 50px;
    background: #CCC;
    position:fixed;
    width: 70%;
}
.content{
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.content p{
    margin: 0px 0px 50px 0px;
}
.footer{
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    background: #CCC;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 70%;
}
.right_panel{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    color:#FFF;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<nav class="user-nav"></nav>

<div class="container">
    
    <div class="viewport">
        
        <div class="header">Header</div><!-- end .header -->
        
        <div class="content">
            LOTS OF CONTENT
        </div><!-- end .content -->
        
        <div class="footer">Footer</div><!-- end .footer -->
        
    </div><!-- end .viewport -->
    
    <div class="right_panel">fixed right panel</div><!-- end .right_panel -->
    
</div><!-- end .container -->
```

Again, any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can not have `.right_panel` width:30% as you have already set  `margin-left: 75px;` on `.container` . So you should now set width of right_panel to `70% - 75px + x = 100;` . Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/709rcw8a/2/

Comment: Thank you, but in the fiddle example you provided there is a gap between the .viewport div and the .right_panel div. I'm trying to make sure everything is "stuck together" and responsive. Are there any other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: I just posted it for demo. you should use `%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using percentages for all columns adding up to 100%, but if you want a fixed width column with two percentages like this, you'll need the 70% column to sit under the fixed width left column. Adjust with padding and use `box-sizing: border-box` on your layout elements to prevent this adding to the total width of the element.

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/709rcw8a/4/

Comment: Thank you. I am using 'box-sizing: border-box' on my actual website but for some reason, it's not working. You fiddle example looks perfect but I can't seem to replicate it on my actual site theme. I'll do some more debugging.

Answer (score 1):

### The Issue:

You are mixing percentage and fixed widths. The reason why `.right_panel` overlaps is because your total percentage is more than 100%:

```
30% + 70% = 100% + 75px;
```

You need to use a percentage for the `.user-nav` as shown in this fiddle:

### [Fix 1: Percentage Only](http://jsfiddle.net/chrissp26/709rcw8a/3/)

```
html{height: 100%;}
body{
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%
}
.user-nav{
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
.viewport{
    width: 60%;
    background: #eee;
}
.header{
    height: 50px;
    background: #CCC;
    position:fixed;
    width: 60%;
}
.content{
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.content p{
    margin: 0px 0px 50px 0px;
}
.footer{
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    background: #CCC;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 60%;
}
.right_panel{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    color:#FFF;
}
```

### [Fix 2: Calc](http://jsfiddle.net/chrissp26/709rcw8a/5/)

Depending on your browser compatibility you could use `calc` instead:

```
width: calc(70% - 75px);
```

That will remove the 75px from the 70% width.

### [Example 3: Positions Only](http://jsfiddle.net/chrissp26/709rcw8a/6/)

In the example above the page uses positions only which you can use to mix percentage and fixed widths but implicitly setting each positioned elements right and left and top and bottom values:

```
html{height: 100%;}
body{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%
}
.user-nav{
    width: 75px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.viewport{
    background: #eee;
}
.header{
    height: 50px;
    background: #CCC;
    position:fixed;
    left: 75px;
    right: 30%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 75px;
    right: 30%;
    bottom: 50px;
}
.footer{
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    background: #CCC;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 75px;
    right: 30%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.right_panel{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Comment: `calc` is still not cross browser! :)

Comment: That's why I said "depending on your browser compatibility" and added it as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks. The exampple you provided looks good but the .user-nav element has to be a fixed width of 75px. It looks best if its that size. I also noticed that you example has horizontal scrolling. How can I fix that issue? adding a overflow: hidden to the body is not ideal.

Comment: the calc example is perfect, but unfortunately it isn't cross-browser. Is there a jQuery work around i can implement?

Comment: The horizontal scrolling is a mistake on my part: .container needs 90% width instead of 100%.

Comment: Check out the 3rd fix in the answer. That uses positions only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.container {
  width: calc(100% - 75px);
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 75px;
}
```

Comment: Calc would work but it isn't cross browser compatible. Is there another way of implementing this? jQuery maybe?